# Button Style( Color) how to change ? Xamarin Cross Platform

Tags: button, xamarin, styles, cross-platform

For Color button I use

```
<Button HorizontalOptions ="StartAndExpand" Image="@+id/table_icon" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
```

but my App is very slow. Is there any other way to change button color. Style ="" I can not use, or do not exist in xaml. ??

Comment: do you want to change the color in C# code?

Comment: Yes, but type Button.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue ; my app slow.  :O

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. Is the problem changing color or that the app has poor performance?

Comment: If i change color my app is poor

Answer (score -1):

in C# code try using

```
button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
```

Change `button` to your button's reference.

Comment: But again do the same only this time in C # is not in XAML. Will it be faster if you do this in C #. And no UIColor.Yellow, more correctly Color.Yellow for Cross platform